# How to access es6 superclass member from its subclass?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

So I'm tooling around with es6 classes but I'm a little stumped. My subclass needs to "shadow"/override a superclass method, but also use a member of the superclass (an instantiated eventemitter). How am I supposed to do this properly?
Superclass (yes Eventemitter3extensionclass is available, also I do need external objects to be able to use the getter):

```
const eventemitter = new WeakMap(); 
export default class Uicomponentsuperclass {
  constructor() {
    eventemitter.set(this, new Eventemitter3extensionclass());
    // constructor
  }

get eventemitter() {
    return eventemitter.get(this);
  }

  ondosomething() {
    eventemitter.get(this).emit("emittedevent");
  }
// Uicomponentsuperclass
}
```

Subclass (showing unsuccessful attempts to access super's eventemitter):

```
export default class Subclass extends Uicomponentsuperclass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // constructor
  }

ondosomething() { // shadowed 
    // eventemitter.get(this).emit("emittedevent"); // 
    // eventemitter.get(super).emit("emittedevent"); //  
    // eventemitter.get(super()).emit("emittedevent"); //  
    // super.eventemitter.emit("emittedevent"); //  
  }
```

Comment: It’d be “this.eventemitter”, it’s a property. Normal class-oriented stuff here.

Comment: `super.eventemitter.emit("emittedevent")` should actually work just fine

Comment: @Bergi if you want to add an answer I'll mark it answered

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick No, I'm not saying you should use it, only that it works and was on your list of attempts. `this.eventemitter.emit("emittedevent")` is the correct way to go, you should accept jfriend's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `ondosomething`, you need to reference `this` and use the `eventemitter` getter defined in your parent:

```
ondosomething() {
    this.eventemitter.emit("emittedevent");
}
```

`this.eventemitter` works like a property access and you can just use it like reading a property (even though it actually has getter code behind it).

This will access the `eventemitter` getter that your base class defines which will get you the `Eventemitter3extensionclass` object you want which you can then call `.emit()` on.

Note: This also assumes `ondosomething` is being called correctly and has the proper value of `this`.  If that is not the case, then that also needs to be corrected.  If you show us the calling code, we could advise on that.  If you are passing `obj.ondosomething` as a callback, you may have to use `.bind()` as in `obj.ondosomething.bind(obj)` to assure the method is called properly bound to its object.

---

FYI, I can't figure out why you're using a `weakMap` to store these.  Is there any reason the event emitter isn't just stored in the instance data of the base class?  It seems that you've already made sure that there is a one-to-one correspondence between `Uicomponentsuperclass` objects and a corresponding `Eventemitter3extensionclass` object.

Comment: Hmmm, re: weakmap I was following a tutorial on how to make "private" members. Just for "fun.

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick - Well, it isn't private if you have a public getter that gets it.  Anyone with your instance can reference `obj.eventemitter` and get it.  So, there appears to be no reason for all this complication.

Comment: I should have said "immutable from the outside" vs "private"

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick - OK, there are ways to accomplish that without the external `weakMap` too, but at least I understand the motivation now.  Did you try this solution to your original problem?

Comment: I might just try it your way ... for now the super invocation is working. I want to apologize for your mental gas spent on this too ... I actually misread a console error leading to my "stumpedness" - the super invocation was actually already working

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the Super class method from sub class, user super.methodName()

Comment: Thanks, yes I did need to use the super keyword, but to access the eventemitter member to call its emit method

Comment: You can make eventemitter class member. This will make it easy to use from sub class.

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi was right again. OMG people, I have to own up. The error was being thrown by a different subclass ... I'm blaming this on my allergies ;-). Actually this works:

```
super.eventemitter.emit("emittedevent")
```